# JavaScript Issue (Maybe async)

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to build a password generator, so that whenever I click the button it will replace the previous password with a new one.

But it seems that `''` is being written to the box value. For the first time it works but after that it doesn't print anything. How can I rectify this issue? Is `password=''` executing after the `while` loop?

```
const btn=document.querySelector('.btn');
let password='',len=0;
const upper='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const lower='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const number='0123456789';
const symbol='@#$%^()_+|{}[]<>/-=';
const all=[...upper,...lower,...number,...symbol];

btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    password='';
    while(len<10){
        password += all[Math.floor(Math.random() * all.length)];
        len=password.length;
    }
    document.querySelector('.box').value=password;
})
```

Comment: You never reset `len` to `p` so the loop never starts. You would avoid all of this if you had declared your variables in the correct scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're facing is that the `len` variable is not being reset to 0 after generating a password. As a result, the while loop condition `while(len<10)` is never met after the first click, and the button click doesn't generate a new password. To fix this, you should reset `len` to 0 before generating a new password.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
let password = '', len = 0;
const upper = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const lower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const number = '0123456789';
const symbol = '@#$%^()_+|{}[]<>/-=';
const all = [...upper, ...lower, ...number, ...symbol];

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    len = 0; // Reset len to 0 before generating a new password
    password = '';
    while (len < 10) {
        password += all[Math.floor(Math.random() * all.length)];
        len = password.length;
    }
    document.querySelector('.box').value = password;
})
```

Now, the `len` variable is properly reset to 0 before generating a new password, ensuring that the while loop works as intended to generate a new password each time the button is clicked.

---

Personally, I recommend declaring your variables in the proper scope. Here is a small example of scoping `len` and `password`.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const upper = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const lower = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
const number = '0123456789';
const symbol = '@#$%^()_+|{}[]<>/-=';
const all = [...upper, ...lower, ...number, ...symbol];

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let len = 0; // Reset len to 0 before generating a new password
    let password = '';
    while (len < 10) {
        password += all[Math.floor(Math.random() * all.length)];
        len = password.length;
    }
    document.querySelector('.box').value = password;
})
```

Comment: Thanks man. I'll take care of that from now on